# Lightbox 2 and Flickr - Where are the next and previous buttons?

Tags: lightbox, flickr, lightbox2

I'm looking to integrate a lightbox2 gallery system with Slick Flickr's ability to pull in a RSS feed containing image information. So far, I have lightbox set up and display correctly, but it fails to show next or previous buttons to cycle through the other images on the gallery.

Here's the current html. The rest is default lightbox2 file stuff.

```
<div class="album-wrapper">  
<?php foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): ?> 
    <div class="photoContainer">  
        <?php
                    if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()) {
                        $img = image_from_description($item->get_description());
                        $full_url = select_image($img, 4);
                        $thumb_url = select_image($img, 0);
                        echo '<a href="' . $full_url . '" rel="lightbox" ><img class="photo' . $i . '" src="' . $thumb_url . '" /></a>'."\n";
                    }
                ?> 
    </div>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `<!doctype html>`on the first line of your code will fix the problem